# Is native library being built into incorrect folder? Android

Tags: android, armv7, android-13, android-native-library

I use Realm sdk , which internally uses the native lib `librealm-jni.so.`

I am noticing some crashes at Google Play reports, indicating that the lib is not found for some architectures:

```
Exception java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/data/com.my.app/app_lib/librealm-jni.so.10.9.0" has bad ELF magic
```

According to Google and several sites i've sen so far, the route should be in the format: `/lib/<abi>/lib<name>.so`,  so the correct path should be `/lib/armabi-v7a/librealm-jni.so.10.9.0`

Is that something that should worry me?

Comment: The lib is not placed there manually, as I understand it is done by the unpackaging process when installing the app. I integrate the Realm project from the maven gradle plugin, I do not manually add the native libs. It has worked fine for years now but suddenly I started getting errors from UnsatisfiedLinkError on some devices.

Comment: Does your app only support armv7a? Because the latest ARM chips no longer support armv7a (32bit) only armv8a (64bit).

Comment: @Robert no, but there are a fair amount of devices that still have 32 bit architecture.

Comment: Just making sure you've seen these 'closed issues' which may be similar (but still somewhat different): https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/6727 https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/7724 So I'm wondering if the devices are rooted and attempting to run a 64-bit apk on a 32-bit device not through the Play Store.

Comment: You wrote that you get this error from "some devices" do you know details on the devices (device model?).

Comment: yes, it happens for devices that still have a 32 bit architecture. F.e. Samsung Galaxy A13

Comment: @MorrisonChang devices are not rooted, are the normal devices of the users. There is a huge spike on the users with the problem once the app was published.